# Can "Microsoft.VC90.CRT" be allowed in debug manifest?

Tags: visual-c++

During debug the R6034 error ("an application has made an attempt to load the c runtime library incorrectly ...")  from my x64 application in VC++ 9.0, I found that one of my debug version manifest file contains 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT'. Why it is not 'Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT'? Is this the potential problem?

Thanks,

- Shunguang

Comment: Its not a good sign but not forbidden. Have both is Really Bad.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to set the properties to force the debug version manifest file to use 'Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT'? it seems the manifest files are automatically created, except some file location parameters.

Comment: They are, have a look at vc/include/crtdefs.h.  You'll see that it generates "DebugCRT" when _DEBUG is #defined.

Comment: I mean inside my project